# Are 32 bit pointers valid in 64 bit process?

Tags: 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

Here is my issue. I implemented a Win 7 x64 process talking to a x32 process by following this [link](http://blog.mattmags.com/2007/06/30/accessing-32-bit-dlls-from-64-bit-code/)

The x64 process retrieves fine a x32 pointer (p_x32 below) to myClass:

```
myClass * POINTER_32 p = (myClass * POINTER_32)p_x32;
```

The trouble is that calling a method on 'p' crashes with memory violation. Indeed, under VS debugger I can see that 'p' members are not in order, i.e. the values are bogus. Digging further I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295762/pointers-using-a-32-bit-dll-in-a-64-bit-service)

Where the author says: "A handle or pointer cannot be serialized, it is only valid in the process that created it". As said above, apparently the pointer can be serialized (I used INT_PTR) but I wonder if "it is only valid in the process that created it" part is correct.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is correct - the pointer is only valid in the originating process because the pointers are interpreted relative to the process's memory space.  Therefore you cannot pass a pointer between processes and dereference it.  You must serialize (deep copy) the actual data and transfer it to the other process.

The exception is you can setup specific "shared memory" spaces between the processes on Windows.  Even then though the pointer values themselves are not guaranteed to be identical.

Answer (score 0):

Each process has it's own virtual memory address space. If you pass pointers across process boundaries, they have a completely different meaning in the target process.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about the pointers validity within the process which created it.

Comment: The serialize (deep copy) approach will not work in my scenario. It is not about data, the methods on myClass 'p' pointer acquired via the COM server are referencing certain third party x32 dlls. Therefore I must be able to dereference it. Is there any practical/proven solution for this scenario? Thanks.